# df vs 'du -x' in VirtualBox

Tags: disk-usage

**SETUP:**

- Ubuntu Linux 18.04
- running in VirtualBox
- shared folders mounted to some `/myShared/A`, `/myShared/B` ... subdirectories

**EXPERIMENT:**

Show remaining disk space

```
> df -h
```

delivers something like

```
/dev/sda5            32G   30G  431M  99% /
```

but

```
> du -xPsch /
```

delivers

```
7,4G    total
```

**QUESTION:**

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

`du` read used size from inodes, here should stay some references from running programs. These references are already deleted but space is still reserved.

`df` read used size as sum of all files

Also you should have for example backup in /mnt/, but you have in this folder mounted external drive. This may cause these differencies in results.

Comment: Do you want to say, that the shared folders occupy inodes which are not excluded by the 'x' option of 'du' ?

Comment: Try unmount `/myShared/A` and also `/myShared/B` , then check if these folders are empty. If you have more mounted filesystems, try to check it, one after one.

Answer (score 0):

DU is more accurate, [this website](http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/12/why-du-and-df-display-different-values.html) explains in detail

In  brief, df uses file information rather than calculating the true size which can be outdated, it also reports on running files in memory. (say you are using dd to create a huge file but not yet completed yet, df would report on it but du wouldn't know yet)